# Set pagenumbers to only appear on the right

Tags: formatting, koma-script, page-numbering, scrpage2

As the title suggests, how can I set my pagenumbers to only appear on the right?

Because I don't know which setting is even responsible for this, where would I have to look to find out what options are set?
(I am using the `\frontmatter`/`\mainmatter` commands, if they have something to do with this...)

`\documentclass` is `scr-book`

This is my main page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook} 

% include settings
\input{components/settings}

% include commands
\input{components/commands}


%\makeindex
    %% inter line spacing
%\linespread{1.0}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter

    \mainmatter

\end{document}
```

My Settings:

```
% Included by MAIN.TEX

\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\normalfont \bfseries}        % Schriftart der Kopfzeile

% manipulate footer
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ifoot[\footertext]{\footertext} % \footertext set in INFO.TEX
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

%% allow sophisticated control structures
\usepackage{ifthen}

% use Palatino as default font
\usepackage{palatino}

% enable special PostScript fonts
\usepackage{pifont}

% make thumbnails
\usepackage{thumbpdf}

%to use the subfigures
%\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{colortbl}


%% show program code\ldots
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{program}

\usepackage{multirow}

%% use colors
\usepackage{color}

%% make fancy math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{yhmath} % f�r die adots 
%% mark text as preliminary
%\usepackage[draft,german,scrtime]{prelim2e}

%% create an index
\usepackage{makeidx}

% for the program environment
\usepackage{float}

%% load german babel package for german abstract
%\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}

% use german characters as well
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       % allow Latin1 characters

% use initals dropped caps - doesn't work with PDF
\usepackage{dropping}


\usepackage{styles/shortoverview}
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
 %% use PostScript graphics
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.epsi}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}{figures/review}} 
 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}

 \usepackage[hypertex,hyperindex=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\else %% reduce output size \pdfcompresslevel=9

 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.JPG,.png,.pdf,.eps}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}} 

 %% Load float package, for enabling floating extensions
 \usepackage{float}

 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}
 %% use pdftex version of hyperref
 \usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red,%
 anchorcolor=red,urlcolor=red,bookmarks=true,%
 bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,plainpages=false%
 bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperindex=false,pdfstartview=%
 ]{hyperref}
\fi
```

Comment: you should provide more information about your document. the best in form of small complete document to which code we can add what you looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

In a comment below the OP mentioned that the document will be onesided.

If the document is onesided, then one of the options `oneside` or `twoside=false` should be set. Then you can use

```
\documentclass[
  %11pt,a4paper,% default
  bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,% <- syntax updated
  headsepline,footsepline,
  footinclude=false,% <- syntax updated
  BCOR=12mm,DIV=13,% <- syntax updated
  oneside
  %twoside=false% <- added -> onesided document
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german,main=english]{babel}% <- really german and not ngerman??
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}% <- changed to KOMA-Script syntax

\usepackage[automark
   %,plainfootsepline% <- if there should be a footsepline on plain pages too
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- successor of deprecated scrpage2; sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot*{\footertext}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

\newcommand*\footertext{Dummy text in the footer}% <- \footertext must be defined 

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in this example
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter in Frontmatter}
\Blindtext
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with the outdated package `scrpage2` (**not recommended**):

```
\documentclass[
  %11pt,a4paper,% default
  bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,% <- syntax updated
  headsepline,footsepline,
  footinclude=false,% <- syntax updated
  BCOR=12mm,DIV=13,% <- syntax updated
  oneside
  %twoside=false% <- added -> onesided document
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german,main=english]{babel}% <- really german and not ngerman??
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}% <- changed to KOMA-Script syntax


\usepackage
  %[plainfootsepline]% <- if there should be a footsepline on plain pages too
{scrpage2}% <- outdated!!
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot[\footertext]{\footertext}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

\newcommand*\footertext{Dummy text in the footer}% <- \footertext must be defined 

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in this example
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter in Frontmatter}
\Blindtext
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

Your code is really outdated. E.g. KOMA-Script options use a key-value-syntax for years. Package `scrpage2` is also deprecated since 2014. Its successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Do you mean, that the pagenumbers should onld appear on the right side on right/odd pages? Then you can use

```
\documentclass[
  %11pt,a4paper,% default
  bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,% <- syntax updated
  headsepline,footsepline,
  footinclude=false,% <- syntax updated
  BCOR=12mm,DIV=13% <- syntax updated
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german,main=english]{babel}% <- really german and not ngerman??
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}% <- changed to KOMA-Script syntax

\usepackage[automark
  %,plainfootsepline <- if there should be a footsepline on plain pages too
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- successor of deprecated scrpage2; sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot*{\footertext}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}% <- r=right, o=odd
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

\newcommand*\footertext{Dummy text in the footer}% <- \footertext must be defined 

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in this example
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter in Frontmatter}
\Blindtext
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: pagenumber only on the right side of odd pages]

But if the page number should be on the right side of even pages too, then `\footertext` must be left on both even and odd pages. Therefore you could use

```
\lofoot*{\footertext}
\lefoot*{\footertext}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\refoot*{\pagemark}
```

But note that the result

[image: page number on the right side of both odd and even pages]

is unusual for a twosided document.

Comment: I inherited this document and was supposed to change as little as possible ... the document will be printed one sided.
Are their some options and settings, that would screw with one sided printing?

Comment: If the document is onesided,  you should set option `oneside` or `twoside=false` for the documentclass. See my updated answer. And again: the code in your question needs a revision.